# FIrebase Firestore onCreate Cloud Function: Object unidentified

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to run a function with the onCreate() method which will be triggered each time a new document is created but i am having issues with it. Below is my code:

```
import functions = require('firebase-functions');
import admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.anotherFunction = functions.firestore
.document('dev_environ/{anotherUserId}')
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

    const userRec = snap.data();

    const newUserData = {
        name: userRec.name,
        email: userRec.email
    };

    return db.doc('dev_environ/'+userRec.uid).set(newUserData);
});
```

The errors i get are:

```
Object [userRec] is possibly 'undefined'.
Object [userRec] is possibly 'undefined'.
Object [userRec] is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Please what am i doing worng? I need good eyes to look at this for me and point my mistakes with a correction to it. I went to the Firebase doc saw an example using the onCreate() but it doesn't explain or say much. I am a newbie to this.

Comment: as per the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.refbuilder#on-create onCreate handler is of the form (snapshot: DataSnapshot, context: EventContext): PromiseLike<any> | any...and DataSnapshot does not have a method .data...may be u ar looking for .value

Comment: Are you saying that i should replace const userRec = snap.data(); with const userRec = snap.value();?. snap has the following methods: createTime, exist, data, get... It doesnt have a value method.

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_database_.datasnapshot i don't see data method here, it is .val()

Comment: @Andrecon Note that searching for "[google-cloud-functions] Object is possibly 'undefined'" on SO would have given you many similar questions.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Yes i am.

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh It doesn't exist. It came back with an error message saying "Property 'value' does not exist on type DocumentSnapshot"

Comment: @Andrecon See the duplicate question

Comment: i think the duplicate question will help u, my idea was to point u in the direction of documentation....value...which i said in my first comment in not there anywhere...it is .val() method...which i said in the last comment...and it has only two properties .app and .instance

Comment: @RenaudTarnec ok.

Comment: @SuryapratapSingh Your doc ref is all about realtime db.

Comment: I have solved it. i changed ...(async (snap, context) {}.... to ....(async (snap:any, context:any){}..... All my errors disappeared. i deployed the function, created a new document and the function was triggered successfully. Thanks to you @RenaudTarnec for your help.

Comment: And also @SuryapratapSingh for your contribution